# Corrplot with only one variable on x axis

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation, r-corrplot

I have a dataset of roughly 200 variables. I'm looking to understand how one of those variables correlates with all the others. However, when I use `corrplot()`, it gives me the full correlation matrix that's `200x200` cells in size - and way to big to be visualized well.

I'll use the `iris` dataset for the reproducible example. Say, here, I only want to see `sepal.length` on the x axis, and all other variables vs `sepal.length` on the y axis.

```
library(corrplot) 
corrplot(cor(iris[,1:4]))
```

Creates this:

[image]

But instead I want just this:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just take the first column of your matrix and suppress the color labels:

```
corrplot(cor(iris[,1:4])[1:4,1, drop=FALSE], cl.pos='n')
```

[image]